# c++ reading process memory with injected DLL

Tags: c++, memory, dll, process, windows-10

The reading works fine until it reaches base+27.058.176(bytes) address. At this address VirtualProtect() failes with error 487 (Attempt to access invalid address).

Why does it return this error? Btw the process uses over 300 MB of memory.

```
if (vInTokens.size() == 3 && !vInTokens.at(0).compare("scan")) {   // vInTokens holds the command and parameters
        int valueToScan = std::stoi(vInTokens.at(1));   // param 1
        Uint offset = std::stoi(vInTokens.at(2));       // param 2
        hits.clear();   // hits is a global variable of type std::vector. in this vector all addresses with valueToScan should get stored.
        Uint scans = 0; // tracks the number of integers (4 bytes) read
        Uint pages = 0; // tracks the number of process pages read

        Uint addr = base;   // base is a global variable that holds the process base address. retrieved with (Uint)GetModuleHandle(NULL)
        Uint addr_max = base + offset; // 0x7FFFFFFF;
        MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi{};

        while (addr < addr_max) {

            // get page
            if (VirtualQuery((LPCVOID)addr, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) == 0) {
                std::cout << "Error: VirtualQuery failed with error " << GetLastError() << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            // update page protection (enable read and write)
            DWORD oldProtect;
            if(VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect) == 0) {
                std::cout << "Error: VirtualProtect(1) failed with error " << GetLastError() << " at " << std::hex << addr << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            // read page memory
            Uint start = addr;
            Uint end = start + mbi.RegionSize;
            while (start < end) {
                int value = *((int*)start);
                if(value == valueToScan)
                    hits.push_back(start);
                scans++;
                start += 4;
            }

            // restore old page protection
            if (VirtualProtect(mbi.BaseAddress, mbi.RegionSize, oldProtect, &oldProtect) == 0) {
                std::cout << "Error: VirtualProtect(2) failed with error " << " with code " << GetLastError() << " at " << std::hex << addr << std::endl;
                break;
            }

            // set values for next page
            pages++;
            addr += mbi.RegionSize;
            mbi = {};
        }

        std::cout << "Scanned " << std::dec << scans << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Pages   " << std::dec << pages << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Found   " << std::dec << hits.size() << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION struct holds a "State" property that is one of the following:

MEM_RESERVE, MEM_COMMIT, MEM_FREE

You can only use VirtualProtect on pages that are actually allocated for use, i.e. the MEM_COMMIT type.

Reserved and free memory pages cannot be read or written to and so you cannot change their protection flags.

A process may take memory of size x, split over many pages that are not continguous.

Comment: Now I added a additional check for state == MEM_COMMIT. But it still returns an error a couple addresses later (base+27.394.048(bytes)). But the error code changed, now it's 87 (The parameter is incorrect.) ??

Comment: You should add sanity checks before the call to VirtualProtect to better understand what is going on, breakpoints/assertions/prints etc. Make sure that the page address and sizes are aligned to the size of a full page. Also, check the *type* property of the area, if is it a MAPPED_* type region then you cannot change its protection to a different one than the one it was initially mapped with.